# How to conditionally enable an ENV Dockerfile directive at build time?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a way to enable a directive of the form

```
ENV SOMEVAR=SOMEVALUE
```

...at build time, e.g. through some `docker buildx build` command-line flag, or through some the setting of some environment variable (in the `docker buildx build` process's environment)?

Alternatively, is there some way that I can modify the value that gets assigned in the `ENV` on the basis of some setting (flag, environment variable, etc.) at build time?

I suppose I could do something like

```
RUN <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ -n $SOMEVAR ]];
    printf -- "\n\nexport SOMEVAR='%s'\n\n" "$SOMEVAR" >> /root/.bashrc
fi
EOF
```

...and then, at build time, include the flag `--build-arg "SOMEVAR=SOMEVALUE"` in the `docker buildx build` command line to have the `printf` line executed during the build, but such maneuvers strike me as extremely fragile.  Plus, I doubt that this comes even close to replicating the effect of the original `ENV SOMEVAR=SOMEVALUE` directive.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the exact semantics you want, you could maybe do something that combines build arguments with environment variables, like this:

```
FROM docker.io/alpine:latest

ARG SOMEVAR=default_value
ENV SOMEVAR=${SOMEVAR}
```

If we build this like:

```
docker build -t envtest .
```

And then run it, we see:

```
$ docker run --rm envtest sh -c 'echo $SOMEVAR'
default_value
```

But if we provide a custom value at build time:

```
docker build -t envtest --build-arg SOMEVAR=my_custom_value .
```

Then we see:

```
$ docker run --rm envtest sh -c 'echo $SOMEVAR'
my_custom_value
```